# using overflow in css

Tags: css, html, scrollbar, overflow

How can i set the width of the first 2 divs to be dynamic (fit the contents width), while the 3rd div should use remaining horizontal space and be horizontally scrollable.

The result i need is that all 3 divs sit side by side and the 3rd div is hoziontally scrollable.

Script i have is as follows

HTML

```
<div id="a">
  <table>
    <tr><td>text</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="b">
  <table>
    <tr><td>text</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="c">
  <table>
    <tr><td>text</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#a
{
float: left;
}
div#b
{
float: left;
}
div#c
{
float: left;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

The above script pushes div3 to the next line, which i dont want.

Comment: just FYI you don't need div in front of #a or #b or #c whenever you are declaring styles for ID's.  You can simply have #a{}, #b{}, #c{} in most cases.

Comment: If you want #c always under #a and #b, then remove the float:left property in #c and instead use clear:both;

Comment: The width of the first 2 parent div containers should fit the size of your content.  You can visually know that by adding a border:solid 1px #000; to the first two styles.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be achieved with pure css. Though I'm happy to be proved wrong.  Is javascript a viable option?

Comment: i have clarified question. @blachawk Thanks for the css syntax tips.

Comment: @Jon P i would prefer to look at a css solution first if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you float `#a` and `#b` to the left, `#c` will fill the rest of the parent's width.

To get `#c` horizontally scrollable, you style its content container as:

```
#c .scroll-content {

    /* You shouldn't do this on a table, but rather on a wrapping container. */
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I made an example [at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kDTLM/5/).

Comment: Sorry, forgot the scrollable feature. Be back soon.

Comment: Nice job afEkenholm, you beat me to it

Comment: Very happy to be proven wrong with my comment in the question

Answer (score 2):

You should set a parent div to hold them all together in the same row. Something like this instead should work.

```
<div id="parent">

<div id="a">
  <table>
    <tr><td>text</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="b">
  <table>
    <tr><td>text</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="c">
  <table>
    <tr><td>text</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

</div>


div#a
{
float: left;
}
div#b
{
float: left;
}
div#c
{
float: left;
}

#parent{
width: 100%;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Also you might want to refactor your code. Since all of the divs are floating left, you might want to use just one class that floats to the left. I hope this helps.

Comment: Not quite what i had in mind, I need only the 3rd div to be scrollable, I have clarified the question. Thanks for the css tip!

Comment: You're welcome. Have you tried adding a min-width to #c? Oh and you should also add a width to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS...

```
  #a {
float:left;
border:solid 1px #000;
width:33%;
}   

#b {
float:left;
border:solid 1px #000;
width:33%;
}

#c {
float:left;
border:solid 1px #000;
width:33%;
}

.scroll{
float:left;
overflow:auto;
width:100%;
}

.content {
width:1000px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

And the HTML...

```
<div id="a">
This is text within my first content box
</div>

<div id="b">
This is text within my second content box 
</div>

<div id="c">
<div class="scroll-content">
This is text within my third content box and this is horizontal and scrollable
</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED JSFIDDLE LINK BELOW AGAIN!!!**

And a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeLqV/1/) - http://jsfiddle.net/GeLqV/1/

Mark, this will work for you now. I now see that you wanted all three divs on the same row, and the last one being able to horizontally scroll.  Look at my jsfiddle demo.  No matter what your screen size will be, all three div's are fluid in size and will stay together (for the most part).

Comment: Fiddle not working (html in script box) and I believe "c" should be on the same line as "a" & "b"

Comment: @blachawk, thanks, but i need the content box to be side by side, not on top of each other.